# How to find the ID of a shared or group calendar to use with MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft365

I've been googling for 30 minutes and can't believe I can't find this. I'd honestly like a *non*programmatic solution.  I'm working with Graph API and attempting to list the events of a group calendar. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) say to use the endpoint `/me/calendarGroups/{id}/calendars/{id}/events`, but as far as I can see they don't say how to get the ID.

The app I'm writing will always use a very specific calendar, so I don't need to enumerate calendars. In other words, I'd like the calendar ID to be hard coded.  Where on earth can I find the ID? I've poked Outlook with a stick a few dozen times and browsed the M365 admin portal. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the Graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and then use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendargroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to enumerate all the Calendar groups to get the Id. You could also take the PR_EntryId from Outlook and convert that to a GraphId using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks, this *seems* to work but I'm having some slight issues. Will check back in after some troubleshooting and accept.